# Suggestion for rabbitmq client in fortran

Tags: fortran, rabbitmq, message-queue, fortran95, fortran2003

I have noticed that there is no given API for fortran to access rabbitmq.

I am considering using C#/.NET as bride to rabbitmq; what would be the most sensible way to bridge Fortran to the C# API? Other suggestions?

The rabbitmq client will trigger events and the fortran client will have to listen to them and process the information.

Any idea?

Thank you very much in advance,

GL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various C Bindings/Clients available on http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html.
I'd use the one of those which suites you best and use the [ISO_C_Binding](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/C+interoperability) to couple it with your Fortran code.

Comment: Thanks, haraldkl. Any link to how to couple it with Fortran? Thanks

Comment: @pacta_sunt_servanda The ISO_C_Binding allows you to call C routines or provide interfaces, that are callable by C. It is part of Fortran 2003 and any documentation on it should be fine. For example have a look into the documentation of your compiler or the link above. For an example wrapper around a C-API, see for example https://bitbucket.org/apesteam/aotus which offers a Fortran wrapper to the Lua C-API.